# Splitting a column vertically using AWK

Tags: awk

If i have +2, i want this to be + 2 as separate columns. I am doing this for a large column so I cannot do it manually.

Edit #1

```
cat maser_neg_test.txt | awk '{print NR, $0}' | awk '{print $1, $2, ((15 * $3) 
+ ((1/4) * $4) + ((1/240) * $5)), (($6)+ ($7/60) + ($8/3600) ,$9}' | awk 
'{printf "%s %-15s %-10s %-10s %-6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 , $5}' > 
maser_neg_test2.txt
```

is my code, which transforms

```
RXSJ00001+0523 00 00 11.78 +05 23 17.4 11992 2016-02-12 51.3 3 10.9 10631 13365
KUG2358+330 00 00 58.10 +33 20 38.0 12921 2012-11-17 36.5 8 4.0 11461 14395
0001233+4733537 00 01 23.30 +47 33 53.7 5237 2010-11-02 39.5 10 3.6 3848 6639 3.5 6358 9196
NGC-7805 00 01 26.76 +31 26 01.4 4850 2006-01-05 43.8 5 6.0 3464 6248 5.6 5968 8799
```

into

```
1 RXSJ00001+0523 0.04908 5.38817 11992 
2 KUG2358+330 0.24208 33.3439 12921 
3 0001233+4733537 0.34708 47.5649 5237 
4 NGC-7805 0.36150 31.4337 4850"
```

but my research advisor noted that in my conversion of

```
dec:
1*(hr) = degree_1
(1/60) * (min) = degree_2
(1/3600) * (sec) = degree_3

degree_1 + degree_2 + degree_3 = dec (degrees)
```

which is the data +05 23 17.4 as hr min sec, that just adding them when the sign is negative does not combine these right. So i'm trying to pull out the sign before doing my calculations and then re-apply it

Edit 2

Is an example of some of the negative cases; sorry this is my first post I wasn't really sure how to format it at first.

```
NGC-23   00 09 53.42  +25 55 25.5   4565  2005-12-18   44.2  30   2.5   3182   5961   2.3   5681   8506
      UM207   00 10 06.63  -00 26 09.4   9648  2010-01-10   25.2  10   2.1   8218  11091   2.1  10802  13723
    MARK937   00 10 09.99  -04 42 38.0   8846  2016-02-04   42.5  10   4.4   7512  10192
     Mrk937   00 10 10.01  -04 42 37.9   8851  2003-11-01   60.4  24   4.1   7428  10286
     NGC-26   00 10 25.86  +25 49 54.6   4589  2005-12-14   41.2   5   5.7   3205   5985   5.1   5705   8531
```

Comment: Please add example input and desired input and what you have tried.

Comment: As for lacking examples, in particular you are not showing a single case of negative sign, which I'm guessing is the problem…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things a lot by using multiple layers of `awk` (and unnecessary `cat`), and thinking of how to "split columns vertically" rather than just solving the problem, which seems to be that for a negative sign you should subtract, rather than add, the minutes and seconds.

So, use intermediate variables and check for the sign (`$5 ~ /^-/`):

```
awk '{ deg = $6/60 + $7/3600; deg = ($5 ~ /^-/) ? $5 - deg : $5 + deg;
       printf "%s %-15s %-10s %-10s %-6s\n",
              NR, $1, ((15 * $2) + (1/4 * $3) + (1/240 * $4)), deg, $8
     }' maser_neg_test.txt
```

(edit: As pointed out by the OP, the original test `$5 < 0` would fail when that field was `-0`.)

Comment: We need to subtract when we have a negative sign? Oh god, i got it completely wrong in my answer....

Comment: This works but when column 5 is 0 but a negative 0, it does not subtract because it is 0 so that's why i thought the separation would be a better idea

Comment: @ripchint Good point, I edited the answer accordingly! (Meanwhile these are still things that you should have mentioned in the question and provided example inputs for.)

Comment: yeah sorry i kept trying to edit my post to keep up with anything i forgot which was a lot

Comment: could you maybe explain what the "deg = ($5 ~ /-/)" says? I'm learning/doing a project at the same time so I'm relatively new to this

Comment: @ripchint That is a way of saying, if $5 contains `-` then $5 - deg, else $5 + deg. Nomenclature is `variable = <condition> ? <return this if condition is true> : <return this if condition is false>` - aka ternary operator

Comment: @ripchint Specifically that part is testing if the degrees field `$5` matches `~` the regular expression (denoted by `//`) where the string begins (`^`) with `-`. The use of the ternary operator `? :` is a shorter way of saying `if ($5 ~ /^-/) { deg = $5 - deg } else { deg = $5 + deg }`.

Comment: Okay this worked wonderfully so thank you and thanks for explaining each character of that, now I actually understand what it does rather than it just working!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
echo '+2' | awk -v FS="" '{print $1" "$2}'
Result:
+ 2
```

If you have a text file (test.txt) with information such as

```
+2
-3
+4
+5
```

and you need output like so:

```
+ 2
- 3
+ 4
+ 5
```

Try this:

```
awk -v FS="" '{print $1" "$2}' test.txt
```

As two commenters have mentioned, it would be good for you to add some example data and the output that you desire. The answer above is just one of the many ways you can format your data.

**EDIT**

In your particular example, you could just use `sed` instead of `cat`'ing the file like so:

```
sed 's_+__g' test.txt | awk '{print NR, $0}' | awk '{print $1, $2, 15*$3 + $4/4 + $5/240, $6 + $7/60 + $8/3600, $9}'
```

`sed` will replace `+` in your file with nothing and then send the output to `awk`. If you have `-` also, you can perhaps remove them by either using `sed` creatively or double-`sed`'ing like so:

```
sed 's_+__g' test.txt | sed 's_-__g' | awk '{print NR, $0}' | awk '{print $1, $2, 15*$3 + $4/4 + $5/240, $6 + $7/60 + $8/3600, $9}'
```

In the scenario above, you may end up removing + and - that are probably wanted in the first column (looks like same code).

Answer (score 0):

You can split the field with the sign into an array. You can keep the first array element as the sign and the second array element as the value:

```
$ awk '{match($6,/([+-])(.*)/,m);print "m[1]=",m[1],"  m[2]=",m[2];print m[1] m[2]+$7/60+$8/3600}' <<<"1 RXSJ00001+0523 00 00 11.78 -05 23 17.4"
#Output
m[1]= -   m[2]= 05
-5.38817
```

Thus you can make all the calculations using m[2] instead of $6.
If you need to print the sign , you just need to print m[1] before m[2]

PS: By ommiting the coma in print and using space you force concatenation (see my example above)

Comment: I think your answer was entirely reasonable given how the question was worded. However, I don't think the third argument of `match` is standard, perhaps you are assuming gawk?

Comment: @Arkku Yest, that is correct. This solution work with GNU awk.